# how can make the button enable and disable in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to see that when the user adds something to the entry field my button gets enabled and then when the user deletes that entry my button gets disabled

Comment: What have you done so far? Is there any code you can show?

Comment: Please have a look at the help center to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to disable a button is to use this code:

```
button = tkinter.Button(root, text='enable/disable'))
def switchButtonState():
    if (button['state'] == tk.NORMAL):
        button['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    else:
        button['state'] = tk.NORMAL
```

To get the input out of a text widget would mean that you would have to run this code:

```
root.after(1000, check_text_box) # I am pretty sure the 1000 is number of milliseconds
```

What the after function does is every 1000 milliseconds, it calls the check_text_box function

Here is the complete code to make it work:

```
def check_to_disable_enable():
    text = text_widget_name.get(1.0, tkinter.END)
    if text == '': # If the textbox is empty
        button['state'] = tk.DISABLED # Disables button
    else: # If the textbox is not empty
        button['state'] = tk.NORMAL # Enables button
# Call this function when the frame comes up
root.after(100, check_to_disable_enable)
```

I realize that this may be a bit confusing and if it is please don't refrain from asking a question. If this answers your question, please mark it answered.

Comment: thank you for answering me but what I am looking for is a bit different rather than what you send me    actually I want to understand when the user adds something in entry widget one of my buttons gets enable and then when the user tries to clean that entry again my button gets disabled  how to code that is something a bit difficult for me